# Why is set cookie only working with redirect from global.asax.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api2, httpcookie

I have a WebApi2 application. The initial load of the site is loading static content for a SPA application. When my `Global.asax.cs` file looks like the following, then the cookie isn't added to the response(as seen in the developer tools in the browser):

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq;

namespace Application
{
    public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (claimsPrincipal != null)
            {
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(".UIROLES", "admin");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I change it to have a condition looking for that cookie and redirecting back to the root page(which is what is loading anyway), then the cookie is showing up(as seen in the developer tools in the browser). Here is the updated `Global.asax.cs` with the redirect:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq;

namespace Application
{
    public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (claimsPrincipal != null)
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[".UIROLES"] == null)
                {
                    var cookie = new HttpCookie(".UIROLES", "admin");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);    
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://localhost/Application");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to read a number of articles on cookies and asp.net, but I can't figure out why the first version isn't working and the second one is. If my UI application requires another trip to the server, I can make it an ApiController call instead to get the data, but it would seem to me that the extra trip to the server shouldn't be necessary.

**UPDATE**: I've tried a lot of the other 'lifecycle' events in the `Global.asax.cs`. I don't see where I have a `HttpContext.Current.User` before the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method(which is where I'm actually getting the roles from), but all of the methods after this point, don't actually seem to write the cookie to the response unless the redirect is in the code. For example, I can add an arbitratry(`new HttpCookie("foo", "bar")`) cookie in the `Application_BeginRequest` method, but the `HttpContext.Current.User` is null at that time.

**Why is this working the way it is?**

**Is there anyway I can get the first set of code to work without the need for a redirect or an additional api call?**